# Intellisense can't see Datatable Name in Dataset generated by hand

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn this tutorial http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28678/1954 in C#, I have created the datatables but when I want to type

```
DsActivitiesTasks.Tasks.AddTasksRow("Email")
```

Intellisense doesn't see Tasks but only TasksRow and TasksDataTable and none have add method.

Did I forget to do something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DsActivitiesTasks` is the name of the class generated by the designer.

`Tasks` is an instance property of that class, so you can only access it from an instance of the dataset.

Try creating a new instance of `DsActivitiesTasks`, like this:

```
new DsActivitiesTasks().Tasks.AddTasksRow("Email");
```

Note that this code will throw away the new dataset; you'll need to store it somewhere in a field or property.

For example:

```
public static readonly DsActivitiesTasks Database = new DsActivitiesTasks();

//In some method:

Database.Tasks.AddTasksRow("Email");
```

Note that datasets are not thread-safe, so you must not work with it on multiple threads.

Comment: Hi thanks, it works great. I have a subsequent question though:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529958/problem-with-dataset-local-variable-and-intellisense-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate `DsActivitiesTasks`.